# filling a grid with one image in indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'd like to make a mural wall of rectangles 100 across and 20 down with space between them and fill with only one image so where the gutters are them image is missing. Is this possible?

Comment: uh... what's keeping you from placing the image once and copying the frame a few times over? Oh, and welcome to GD.SE! If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 3):

Use a **Compound Path**.

1. Create your rectangles. (I suggest clicking and dragging the **Rectangle Frame Tool** to the desired area, and without letting go of the mouse, use the **Up/Down** and **Left/Right** arrows on your keyboard until you get the desired grid of rectangles. The gutter between the rectangles can be adjusted under **Layout** > **Margins and Columns** before you begin this step.)
2. With all your rectangles selected, go to **Object** > **Paths** > **Make Compound Path**.
3. Select your rectangles (which should now all function as one unit), and **File** > **Place** your image.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to prepare all your rectangles and to import your image in one of them.

- Double click ont he image so you can place it where you want (or maintain click on the double circle one the center of the placeholder) to cover all the rectangles.
- Once it's well placed, double click on this rectange to select the image and  <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> (copy).
- Then go to each other rectangle and <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> (paste in). This way, each copy of the image will keep the initial position

Another way more simple solution :

- Create a layer and place the image on it;
- Create on above it another layer and make a tansparent table with white bordered cells, so you'll have the wanted margin between images.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you're thinking about this the wrong way.

There's no *visual* difference between an array of image frames all filled with slightly different parts of the same image, and a single image overlaid by a grid of strokes with the color set to the "Paper" swatch.

There are some *practical* differences, however. If you need to adjust or resize the image, a single image frame is going to be a lot easier to manage than 2,000 smaller ones that must be kept in sync. To swap out the image, the job is as easy as dragging and dropping in the new image, which is going to be a whole lot faster than relinking 2,000 frames.Your INDD will also be considerably smaller.